# Unobvious crash due to unbalanced call to dispatch group

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I received an crash report `BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBDISPATCH: Unbalanced call to dispatch_group_leave()`.

The anonymized code which stacktrace points on, looks like:

```
 func updateHealthKitData(from startDate: Date, to endDate: Date, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
     let group = DispatchGroup()
     group.enter()
     self.hkDataStore.getData1(startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate, completion: {(data1) in
         if let samplesToProcess = data1 {
             self.processData1(data: samplesToProcess, completion: {() in
                 group.leave()
             })
         } else {
             group.leave()
         }
     })
     group.enter()
     self.hkDataStore.getData2(startDate: startDate, completion: {(data2) in
         if let samplesToProcess = data2 {
             self.processData2(data: samplesToProcess, completion: {() in
                 group.leave()
             })
         } else {
             group.leave()
         }
     })

     group.notify(queue: .main) {
         completion()
     }
 }
```

The exception came from queue `com.apple.HealthKit.HKHealthStore.client`.
The tasks `getData2` and `getData1` query health-kit in background queue.

I read that dispatch group is thread-safe enough i.e. it can be used from other queues without `synchronize`.
The Group dispatch enters twice before doing tasks and only after that it waits for balance to notify when tasks will be done.
I double checked that any completions (and nested ones) aren't called twice which may lead to extra call to dispatch group.

What can be wrong here ? Thanks in advance for any help and thoughts!

Comment: I am also getting the same issue when I use dispatch group with healthkit. I tried to use defer{} inside the closure to avoid two leave() calls but the app is still crashing with the same error.

Answer (score 2):

First, you are right, `DispatchGroup` is indeed thread-safe. That’s not the issue.

You get this “Unbalanced call” error if you `leave` more times than you `enter`.

So, one or more of these four routines, `getData1`, `processData1`, `getData2`, or `processData2` must be calling its respective completion handler more than once. In that scenario, for one `enter` call, you have more than one `leave` call.

We would need to see these `getData` and `processData` routines to diagnose it further, but I suspect that you’ll be able to find it.

---

You said:

> I double checked that any completions (and nested ones) aren't called twice which may lead to extra call to dispatch group.

Nonetheless, this has to be the problem. I’d suggest verifying this empirically, perhaps temporarily adding logging statements and perhaps a boolean test, for example:

```
func updateHealthKitData(from startDate: Date, to endDate: Date, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    var hasRunAlready1 = false
    self.hkDataStore.getData1(startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate, completion: {(data1) in
        if let samplesToProcess = data1 {
            self.processData1(data: samplesToProcess, completion: {() in
                if hasRunAlready1 { fatalError("Has run 1 already - a") }
                hasRunAlready1 = true
                print("1a")
                group.leave()
            })
        } else {
            if hasRunAlready1 { fatalError("Has run 1 already - b") }
            hasRunAlready1 = true
            print("1b")
            group.leave()
        }
    })

    group.enter()
    var hasRunAlready2 = false
    self.hkDataStore.getData2(startDate: startDate, completion: {(data2) in
        if let samplesToProcess = data2 {
            self.processData2(data: samplesToProcess, completion: {() in
                if hasRunAlready2 { fatalError("Has run 2 already - a") }
                hasRunAlready2 = true
                print("2a")
                group.leave()
            })
        } else {
            if hasRunAlready2 { fatalError("Has run 2 already - b") }
            hasRunAlready2 = true
            print("2b")
            group.leave()
        }
    })

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        completion()
    }
}
```